# How to deal with Error in fromJSON("transcripts_ru_2023-01-16.json") : not all data was parsed (0 chars were parsed out of a total of 30 chars)?

Tags: r, json

I am trying to load a JSON file in `R`, but I keep receiving the following error:

```
Error in fromJSON("transcripts_ru_2023-01-16.json") : 
  not all data was parsed (0 chars were parsed out of a total of 30 chars)
```

Here is the code I am using:

```
install.packages("rjson")

library("rjson")

data <- fromJSON("transcripts_ru_2023-01-16.json")
```

Data available here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1MeKgd2hyicXjuZH1JnhFxNyFwpBXaFoj/view?usp=sharing

Comment: The "data" appears to be a link (or perhaps the file itself?) to a zip file that expands to a 202 MB json file. Hardly a minimal example. I'm guessing that you should be downloading using a zip-capable function or utility.

Comment: I think you should search on how to download files from google drive, but use a small file rather than a gigantic file. My close vote can be reversed if you come up with code that is not succeeding at the task of downloading a small file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a newline-delimited JSON; each individual line is a separate JSON object.
As it's quite small for what it is, you can probably load it all to memory with something like this:

```r
tscr <- jsonlite::stream_in(file("transcripts_en_2023-01-16.json"))
#> opening file input connection.
#>  Found 500 records... /.../ Imported 9349 records. Simplifying...
#> closing file input connection.

tibble::as_tibble(tscr)
#> # A tibble: 9,349 × 10
#>    date        persons transcript_unfiltered kremlin_id place title teaser tags 
#>    <chr>       <list>  <chr>                      <int> <chr> <chr> <chr>  <lis>
#>  1 1999-12-31… <list>  Vladimir Putin: Dear…      22280 "The… New … ""     <chr>
#>  2 1999-12-31… <list>  Vladimir Putin: Good…      22326 "The… Addr… ""     <chr>
#>  3 1999-12-31… <list>  Boris Yeltsin: Dear …      24080 "The… Stat… ""     <chr>
#>  4 2000-01-04… <list>  Question: Mr Putin, …      24377 "Mos… Inte… ""     <chr>
#>  5 2000-01-11… <list>  Vladimir Putin: Dear…      24116 "Sta… Spee… ""     <chr>
#>  6 2000-01-15… <list>  Sergei Dorenko: Mr. …      24123 ""    Inte… ""     <chr>
#>  7 2000-01-18… <list>  Question: You have s…      24125 "Mos… Conv… ""     <chr>
#>  8 2000-01-18… <list>  Vladimir Putin: I am…      24124 "Mos… A sp… ""     <chr>
#>  9 2000-01-21… <list>  Vladimir Putin: Dist…      21505 "Mos… Open… ""     <chr>
#> 10 2000-01-23… <list>  Nikolai Svanidze: Th…      24126 ""    Inte… ""     <chr>
#> # ℹ 9,339 more rows
#> # ℹ 2 more variables: transcript_filtered <chr>, wordlist <list>
```

<sup>Created on 2023-07-17 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>